# Ugly hack for recording a UDP stream in VLC.

Tags: python, stream, udp, vlc, recording

I recently had to pick up my pretty rusty coding knowledge to try and create a simple script to record a documentatory stream of our stage camera so that, instead of someone having to stick around and create cumbersome recording schedules all day, you could just run show name executables in, say, Scheduler and the stream would be recorded, renamed and transferred to a publicly accessible folder.

I've had some issues with the recording, mainly with making sure that nothing goes wrong while the script runs. Optimally, the computer wouldn't need options such as .setFocus to send commands to VLC since, well, what if someone deselects VLC while it's about to send the record command?

I wrote this code after spending about a week of doing research around here and it's pretty straightforward, but I'd appreciate all feedback on how it could be optimized. Obviously, this is more of a alpha stage phase until we get a dedicated api programmer to integrate stuff with our hardware, but I've always liked automating tasks.

```
import time, SendKeys, os
# Start VLC using a udp stream playlist file

from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Start(
    cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe" '
             u'--started-from-file "C:\\Program Files     (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\udp.xspf"')
qwidget = app.QWidget
qwidget.Wait('ready')
qwidget.SetFocus()

time.sleep(3)

# Record for 9000 seconds = 2h30m

SendKeys.SendKeys("+r")

time.sleep(9000)

# Quit VLC, leaving a non-corrupted .ts video file

app.Kill_()

# Ugly hack code for renaming the file. The folder is supposedly empty given that the code, if successful in
# creating a file here, must also be successful in moving the same file to the final directory.
# File is renamed with camera name, show name and date and time for the recording.
# The original naming format for VLC is something like
# vlc-record-2015-11-16-08h59m01s-udp___xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx_xxxx-.ts
# (Optimally I'd like to change the file output format to mp4 or similar, but couldn't figure out
# a way to use both Start from Playlist file and --sout options in the command line interface.

os.chdir(r"C:/VLC")

# Necessary?

FileName = str(os.listdir("C:/VLC"))[2:59]
ShowName = str("Swanlake")

os.rename(FileName, "Scenbild " + ShowName + " " + FileName[13:29] + ".ts")

# Using os.rename to move the renamed file to the new location.

NewFileName = str(os.listdir("C:/VLC"))[2:39]
OldFileLocation = str(r"C:/VLC/")
NewFileLocation = str(r"C:/videotest/svansjon/")

time.sleep(3)

os.rename(OldFileLocation + NewFileName, NewFileLocation + NewFileName)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, try to clarify a bit your scenario. If you want to make VLC stop after a while you can just pass it the ` --run-time=9000` option.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of feedback I'm looking for! How to increase the effectivity of this jumble of spaghetti code. I'll mess around with the --run-time option.

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm essentially telling VLC to open a playlist containing a udp stream address, record it for a given length of time and then stop the recording. Seeing as VLC leaves a non-corrupt file when shut down in the middle of the recording, it seemed like the easiest way to do it.

Right now, the script works; I get a renamed, moved and working video file at the end of the script, but VLC shows an abnormal runtime termination. I'll see if it improves with @aergistal 's suggestion. app.Kill_() seems like a brutish way to work it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a single line. Note that I'm using the console version of VLC, I think it's `cvlc.exe` on Windows. The example is for an `MPEG-TS` input stream:

```
cvlc <input> --play-and-exit --run-time 9000 \
--sout="#std{access=file,mux=ts,dst='/path/to/output.ts'}"
```

You can make a script to configure the input, duration, destination path and file name and record directly there.

Comment: That's brilliant. I was just starting to mess around with [this guide](https://blog.sourcefabric.org/en/news/blog/2077/), but thanks for clarifying.

I'm still having trouble with --sout when I want to transcode the stream to m4v. it's not just mux=mp4v apparently...

Comment: You can mux into `mp4`. If you really want to transcode see https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/